# Print values from SHOW TABLES query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to run my SHOW TABLES; query using PHP and print the results. However, the data being printed is only the first result. I'm assuming that what I am doing wrong is something simple, but, I've been trying for a while and can't get it to work. Code is below:

```
<?php
    $sel_query="SHOW TABLES";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);
    $dataArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $values = print implode(", ", $dataArray)."<br>";
    echo $values;
         
    foreach ($dataArray as $tables) {
        echo "$tables <br>";
    }
?>
```

Does anyone know what I need to change to make all of the values print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `mysqli_fetch_assoc` on each row, a common way is to use a `while()` loop which reads each row from the query and stops after the last row (`mysqli_fetch_...` returns NULL when the last row has been returned)...

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);
 while ($dataArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {
     echo implode(", ", $dataArray)."<br>";
 }
```